# Tikz pgfplot graph shifted right

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been trying this for some time now, but I cannot get it to work. Basically I try to plot a Gauss CDF, but the graph sits on the right margin on the page and a good chunk is not visible at all due to being outside.

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gausscdf}{2}{
  \pgfmathparse{1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((x-#1)/#2)^3 - 1.5976*(x-#1)/#2))}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        style={mark=none, domain=-4:4,samples=10,smooth},
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        axis lines=middle,
        x=0.1*\textwidth,
        restrict x to domain=-3:3,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        legend style={draw=none}
    ]
        \addplot[color=orange] {gausscdf(0,1)};
        \addplot[color=red] {gausscdf(0,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please add to your code the document class and the required packages. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong exactly, but defining the function using `declare function` as in the code below seems to fix it.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 declare function={
    gausscdf(\x,\a,\b) = 1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\a)/\b)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\a)/\b));
  }
]
    \begin{axis}[
        style={mark=none, domain=-4:4,samples=10,smooth},
        axis lines=middle,
        x=0.1*\textwidth,
        restrict x to domain=-3:3,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        legend style={draw=none}
    ]
        \addplot[color=orange] {gausscdf(x,0,1)};
        \addplot[color=red] {gausscdf(x,0,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```